# Include multiple page ids in loop

Tags: loop, pages

Haven’t slept in about 30 hours now, can someone please help as the below code doesn’t work, it just displays all posts etc :|

```
<?php $args = array
  (
        'page' => array(139, 54)
  );

  $loopy = new WP_Query($args);
  while ($loopy->have_posts()) : $loopy->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="item"><?php the_title(); 
              echo '<br ?>';

        echo '</div>';      
  endwhile;
```

?>

Answer (score 3):

`page` is not an accepted parameter for WP_query , you can use `page_id`  but that doesn't accept an array , only one specific ID, so just use  `post__in` like this:

```
<?php $args = array(
        'post__in' => array(139, 54)
  );

  $loopy = new WP_Query($args);
  while ($loopy->have_posts()) : $loopy->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="item"><?php the_title(); 
              echo '<br ?>';

        echo '</div>';      
  endwhile;
```

you can read more about the [accepted parameters of wp_query at the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters)

Comment: Thanks, doesn't seem to work though and the page ids are there

Comment: or post_type => "any" if you are not expecting pages only

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

I have to tell wordpress I want posts in conjunction with Bainternet's code:

```
'post_type' => 'page',
```

Comment: Where to put ''post_type' => 'page'.... Please provide me the full code for this problem.